# How can i add a PDF to another in iTextSharp?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I have looked everywhere for this but cant find the answer that works. I have 2 input PDF's (only ever 2).

I want to add PDF2 to the bottom of PDF1 (new page) and then output both as PDF3.

Can anyone help, if you submit any code if its in vb.net that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the PdfWriter.GetImportedPage...

For example:

```
'' Create your blank PDF
Dim pdfDoc As Document = New Document(New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height))
Dim pdfWriter As PdfWriter = pdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("yourPDF.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
pdfDoc.Open()

'' Create a reader to read in your PDF 2
Dim bgReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("pdf2.pdf"))
Dim bg As PdfImportedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(bgReader, 1)


'' add the template beneath content
pdfWriter.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(bg, 0, 0)

'' now do the same for PDF1
bgReader = new PdfReader("pdf1.pdf")
bg = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(bgReader,1)
pdfWriter.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(bg,0,0)

'' don't forget to close the doc which will save it
pdfDoc.Close()
```

This is one of a few ways to do.. Haven't tested the code, though shouldn't be too far out :)

EDIT:

See, as far as I am aware you can't actually change PDF1. you have to create PDF3, made up from PDF1 and PDF2. Hence above this is what we're actually doing.

The other thing you could do is load in the document which forms the basis of your main one and then create a PdfStamper to which you will write to. So assuming PDF1 is your main.

```
Dim reader as PdfReader = New PdfReader("pathToPDF1")
Dim stamper as new PdfStamper(reader, New FileStream("PathToSaveYourNewPdfTo.pdf"), IO.FileMode.Create)
```

Now, read in the content PDF2

```
Dim bgReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("pdf2.pdf"))
Dim bg As PdfImportedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(bgReader, 1)
```

If you want to add this UNDER your template then call GetUnderContent. You can position WHERE you want this by supplying X and Y coordinates '0,0' in my code example. Remembering that the coordinates originate from bottom left on a PDF.

```
'' add the template beneath content, 1 indicates pagenumber of the doc you loaded in
stamper.GetUnderContent(1).AddTemplate(bg, 0, 0)
```

If you want to add to the TOP of your template then you call GetOverContent and can use the same positioning properties

```
stamper.GetOverContent(1).AddTemplate(bg, 0, 0)
```

Not sure if i am missing something else in your comments..?...

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it works but it just adds the new document to the top of the current one so it actually overlaps the first document, the problem i am having is getting the new page to apped the first one, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Ok well that document mentioned seems to be corrupt and that explains that issue. The problem now is that i can only seem to add the new pdf above the first one even after swapping them around :-S

Comment: Thanks for this, if it originates from bottom left, if i leave it as 0,0 will it just append the first one? See the output i have at the moment (pdf3) is doing things ok but the two input pdf's are just the wrong way round, so the one i need at the bottom is at the top, thats the only problem.

Comment: Without actually coding up your entire requirement I'm not sure what else to suggest. The code examples work, in that you needed to bring PDF's together into a single PDF. The placement of these PDF's is done using the co-ordinates, I would suggest playing with them to figure out best positioning.

Answer (score -2):

You can merge Pds using `"ITextSharp"`...here is the good example which i tried myself in my recent project...you can get good idea from it...

[Pdf Merge Issue in ItextSharp (After Merging Pdfs don't retain their Values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210002/pdf-merge-issue-in-itextsharp-after-merging-pdfs-dont-retain-their-values)