# Links are not working while Merge PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

My task is to merge multiple pdf to single pdf and I can achieve the merger pdf but I am facing issue in the internal links (named destination) are missed up from second pdf where as its working in first pdf. My issues are similiar to the below post.

[Pdf Merge Issue in ItextSharp (After Merging Pdfs don't retain their Values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210002/pdf-merge-issue-in-itextsharp-after-merging-pdfs-dont-retain-their-values)

But I did not achieve this.

My code are below.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document document = new Document();

            string[] fileNames = @"D:\PDF_Protect\ToMerge\Test\pdf1.pdf;D:\PDF_Protect\ToMerge\Test\pdf2.pdf;D:\PDF_Protect\ToMerge\Test\pdf3.pdf;".Split(';');
            string outFile = @"D:\PDF_Protect\ToMerge\output\merged.pdf";

           //merge one
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                var pdfDestination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
                //var pdfAction = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, pdfDestination, pdf);
                //pdf.SetOpenAction(pdfAction);
                pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            document.Close();
        }
    }
```

Kindly guide me how to regenerate the links working throughout the merged pdf.

Comment: Why are you setting an open action every time you add a new document. That doesn't make sense, does it? Also, you consolidate the named destinations, but I don't see you using the `AddNamedDestinations()` method anywhere to add the named destinations of the original document to the `PdfCopy` instance. In that case, it is only normal that the destinations are "not working". You aren't adding them!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for your quick response. I was new to links/bookmarks, Now I commented the action part, I have referred this link for addnamed destinations [link](https://github.com/kusl/itextsharp/blob/master/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/ConcatenateNamedDestinations.cs). As per my understanding they are taking named destination from second pdf and add to first pdf, Am I right? But I have to process more pdf files. Is it Possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just adapt the code. Make sure you always use the correct offset.

Comment: correct offset meaning all pdf page size ?

Comment: Not page size, but number of pages.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Okay. For instance, want to get named destination details from pdf2,pdf3 and stored in pdf1. I will try at my end and get back if I face any issue/concern.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I tried this code `Dictionary<string,string> destination=SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, false);
                pdf.AddNamedDestinations(destination,new PdfReader(fileNames[0].ToString()).NumberOfPages);` but it does not helped me.

Comment: Are you sure that `false` is the right parameter? Also: do you know what you are actually doing? What's inside the original PDFs? Are you sure it are named destinations? What if they are actually local goto operations? I can't help you if you don't know the difference.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I may be wrong, please correct/guide me on this part. As per my understanding, I am getting/collecting all the named destination from all the PDFs and mapping to first pdf. As per the example link it mentioned as false.., So I include the same in my code. I am looking to remapping/rearranging internal links to toc page.  Is I need to use this method for internal link mapping `reader.MakeRemoteNamedDestinationsLocal();`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, Your help is needed.

Comment: Please contact http://itextpdf.com for premium support.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I hope this feature is not available in open source of Itextsharp. Thanks for the information.